# How to fill the background of the top most view on scroll using ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a view with a background color of green like this in the top-most of my `ScrollView`:

[image: This is the unscrolled state of the view]

I want to keep the bouncing effect, but when I scroll downwards (to go up), it the white background color like this:

[image: This is when I scroll up]

I want to keep it the same color so it doesn't show the background color as I scroll (in this case, it's white). How do I achieve this? Here's my code so far:

```
NavigationView {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(spacing: 19) {
                VStack { // This is the view with the green background
                    // some code goes here
                }.frame(height: proxy.safeAreaInsets.top + 171, alignment: .top)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.PRIMARY_BACKGROUND)
            
                // some code goes here
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add a Zstack() right after NavigationView() and give it a background color.

```
NavigationView {
    ZStack{
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 19) {
                    VStack { // This is the view with the green background
                        // some code goes here
                    }.frame(height: proxy.safeAreaInsets.top + 171, alignment: .top)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.PRIMARY_BACKGROUND)

                    // some code goes here
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .background(Color.PRIMARY_BACKGROUND)
}
```